# I show an error message when I parse XML

Tags: ios, swift, xml-parsing

I am new to Swift programming. I have 2 classes to parse RSS and show the datas. It's named `ParseRSSFeed` and `DetailVC`. But I can't see the datas in `TableView` when I want to parse.

But if I call methods of `XMLParserDelegate` in `DetailVC`, it works. Probably I did a mistake while calling the methods from another class.

My code is as below.

What did I overlook?

**ParseRSSFeeds class to parse XML**

```
import UIKit

class ParseRSSFeeds: XMLParser, XMLParserDelegate{
    var parser = XMLParser()
    var news = NSMutableArray()
    var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
    var element = NSString()
    var header = NSMutableString()
    var link = NSMutableString()
    var desc = NSMutableString()
    var date = NSMutableString()

    func parseFromUrl(){
        news = []
        parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: NSURL(string: "https://www.wired.com/feed/rss")! as URL)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        element = elementName as NSString

        if (elementName as NSString) .isEqual(to: "item") {
            elements = NSMutableDictionary()
            elements = [:]
            header = NSMutableString()
            header = ""
            link = NSMutableString()
            link = ""
            desc = NSMutableString()
            desc = ""
            date = NSMutableString()
            date = ""
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        if element .isEqual(to: "title"){
            header.append(string)
        }else if element .isEqual(to: "link"){
            link.append(string)
        }else if element .isEqual(to: "description"){
            desc.append(string)
        }else if element .isEqual(to: "pubDate") {
            date.append(string)
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if (elementName as NSString) .isEqual(to: "item") {
            if !header .isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(header, forKey: "title" as NSCopying)
            }
            if !link .isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(link, forKey: "link" as NSCopying)
            }
            if !desc .isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(desc, forKey: "description" as NSCopying)
            }
            if !date .isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(date, forKey: "pubDate" as NSCopying)
            }

            news.add(elements)
        }
    }
}
```

**DetailVC (It includes table view to show RSS feeds.)**

```
import UIKit

class DetailVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tblNews: UITableView!

    let parser = ParseRSSFeeds()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ParseRSSFeeds().parseFromUrl()
        tblNews.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return parser.news.count - parser.news.count + 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tblNews.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        if cell .isEqual(NSNull.self) {
            cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("cell", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UITableViewCell
        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = (parser.news.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).value!(forKey: "title") as? String
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = (parser.news.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).value!(forKey: "description") as? String

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this statement `parser.news.count - parser.news.count + 5` ? it will always be 5

Comment: change it  to only `parser.news.count`

Comment: There are unrelated problems in this code: 1. You shouldn't parse from a URL, because it will perform synchronous network request, blocking the main thread while the request is in progress. You should asynchronously retrieve the data with `URLSession` and then parse it from the `Data`. Or, if you should do this on a background thread and then dispatch the UI update to the main thread. 2. You should remove remove all these references to `NS` classes and use their Swift equivalents. E.g. replace `if (elementName as NSString) .isEqual(to: "item") { ... }` with `if elementName == "item" { ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `ParseRSSFeeds` instances, the `parser` property and the one you create in `viewDidLoad`. So, `viewDidLoad` is creating a second instance of `ParseRSSFeeds`, requesting and parsing the response, and then discarding those results, leaving the separate `parser` property untouched.

You should instead have `viewDidLoad` reference the `parser` property rather than creating new instance of `ParseRSSFeeds`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    parser.parseFromUrl()
    ...
}
```

Comment: Little touch, big difference :) Thank you.